# How to access the html nested within multiple shadowRoot using Selenium and Python

Tags: python, selenium, shadow-dom, selectors-api, queryselector

I am trying to build a bot to solve Wordle puzzles on the website (https://www.powerlanguage.co.uk/wordle/)

I am using selenium to enter a guess then attempting to inspect the page to see which guesses are correct and incorrect

I can see this information when I inspect the element on chrome but using selenium the html returned is much shorter and points to a javascript app? Is there a way to return the inspect html in selenium? Here is my code.

```
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException
from selenium.common.exceptions import ElementClickInterceptedException
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r"/Users/1/Downloads/chromedriver", options=chrome_options)
driver.get("https://www.powerlanguage.co.uk/wordle/")
time.sleep(1)
sends=driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body")
sends.click()
sends.send_keys("adieu")
sends.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
sends.get_attribute('innerHTML')
```

This is what inner html returns
[image]

And this is what I can see on inspection on the website
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The desired information interms of [innerHTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70120537/cannot-get-all-html-when-using-requests-get-or-webdriver-get/70121383#70121383) is within multiple [#shadow-root (open)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56380091/how-to-locate-the-shadow-root-open-elements-through-cssselector).

[image: multiple_shadow_root]

---

### Solution

To extract the information you need to use [`shadowRoot.querySelectorAll()`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55761810/how-to-automate-shadow-dom-elements-using-selenium/55763793#55763793) and you can use the following [Locator Strategy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Code Block:

  ```
  driver.get("https://www.powerlanguage.co.uk/wordle/")
  time.sleep(1)
  sends=driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "/html/body")
  sends.click()
  sends.send_keys("adieu")
  sends.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
  inner_texts = [my_elem.get_attribute("outerHTML") for my_elem in driver.execute_script("""return document.querySelector('game-app').shadowRoot.querySelector('game-row').shadowRoot.querySelectorAll('game-tile[letter]')""")]
  for inner_text in inner_texts:
  print(inner_text)
  ```
- Console Output:

  ```
  <game-tile letter="a" evaluation="absent" reveal=""></game-tile>
  <game-tile letter="d" evaluation="absent"></game-tile>
  <game-tile letter="i" evaluation="correct"></game-tile>
  <game-tile letter="e" evaluation="absent"></game-tile>
  <game-tile letter="u" evaluation="absent"></game-tile>
  ```

---

### References

You can find a couple of relevant discussions in:

- [Can't locate elments within shadow-root (open) using Python Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65445170/cant-locate-elments-within-shadow-root-open-using-python-selenium/65452620#65452620)
- [How to get past a cookie agreement page using Python and Selenium?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65734432/how-to-get-past-a-cookie-agreement-page-using-python-and-selenium/65735009#65735009)

Comment: Fantastic that's pretty much exactly what I am looking for, what needs to be altered in the path to get the inner HTML for rows 2-6 of the grid when I send a guess? I tried sending a second guess before calling "inner_texts" and it just returned the same console output above. `sends.send_keys("adieu")
sends.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
time.sleep(2)
sends.send_keys("groan")
sends.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
time.sleep(2)`

Comment: @amc-man That's subject to investigation :) Feel free to raise a new question as per your new requirement.

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking for a complete Python Selenium solution for solving the Wordle Game programmatically, here's one that uses the [SeleniumBase](https://github.com/seleniumbase/SeleniumBase) framework. The solution comes with a YouTube video: [Solving Wordle using SeleniumBase](https://youtube.com/watch?v=wSvehy4u_xw), as well as [the Python code of the solution](https://github.com/seleniumbase/SeleniumBase/blob/master/examples/wordle_test.py), and a GIF of what to expect:

[image]

The code uses special SeleniumBase `::shadow` selectors in order to pierce through multiple layers of Shadow-DOM. Here's the code below, which can be run after calling `pip install seleniumbase` to get all the Python dependencies:

```py
import ast
import random
import requests
from seleniumbase import __version__
from seleniumbase import BaseCase

class WordleTests(BaseCase):
    word_list = []

    def initalize_word_list(self):
        js_file = "https://www.powerlanguage.co.uk/wordle/main.e65ce0a5.js"
        req_text = requests.get(js_file).text
        start = req_text.find("var La=") + len("var La=")
        end = req_text.find("],", start) + 1
        word_string = req_text[start:end]
        self.word_list = ast.literal_eval(word_string)

    def modify_word_list(self, word, letter_status):
        new_word_list = []
        correct_letters = []
        present_letters = []
        for i in range(len(word)):
            if letter_status[i] == "correct":
                correct_letters.append(word[i])
                for w in self.word_list:
                    if w[i] == word[i]:
                        new_word_list.append(w)
                self.word_list = new_word_list
                new_word_list = []
        for i in range(len(word)):
            if letter_status[i] == "present":
                present_letters.append(word[i])
                for w in self.word_list:
                    if word[i] in w and word[i] != w[i]:
                        new_word_list.append(w)
                self.word_list = new_word_list
                new_word_list = []
        for i in range(len(word)):
            if (
                letter_status[i] == "absent"
                and word[i] not in correct_letters
                and word[i] not in present_letters
            ):
                for w in self.word_list:
                    if word[i] not in w:
                        new_word_list.append(w)
                self.word_list = new_word_list
                new_word_list = []

    def test_wordle(self):
        self.open("https://www.powerlanguage.co.uk/wordle/")
        self.click("game-app::shadow game-modal::shadow game-icon")
        self.initalize_word_list()
        keyboard_base = "game-app::shadow game-keyboard::shadow "
        word = random.choice(self.word_list)
        total_attempts = 0
        success = False
        for attempt in range(6):
            total_attempts += 1
            word = random.choice(self.word_list)
            letters = []
            for letter in word:
                letters.append(letter)
                button = 'button[data-key="%s"]' % letter
                self.click(keyboard_base + button)
            button = 'button[data-key="↵"]'
            self.click(keyboard_base + button)
            self.sleep(1)  # Time for the animation
            row = 'game-app::shadow game-row[letters="%s"]::shadow ' % word
            tile = row + "game-tile:nth-of-type(%s)"
            letter_status = []
            for i in range(1, 6):
                letter_eval = self.get_attribute(tile % str(i), "evaluation")
                letter_status.append(letter_eval)
            if letter_status.count("correct") == 5:
                success = True
                break
            self.word_list.remove(word)
            self.modify_word_list(word, letter_status)

        self.save_screenshot_to_logs()
        print('\nWord: "%s"\nAttempts: %s' % (word.upper(), total_attempts))
        if not success:
            self.fail("Unable to solve for the correct word in 6 attempts!")
        self.sleep(3)
```

This solution requires minimum SeleniumBase version `2.4.0` (or newer) due to updated Shadow-DOM methods. ([Here are the Release Notes of that version.](https://github.com/seleniumbase/SeleniumBase/releases/tag/v2.4.0))

Note that SeleniumBase tests are run using `pytest`. Also, the Wordle website appears slightly differently when opened using headless Chrome, so don't use Chrome's headless mode when running this example.